# No /etc/quagga folder and no quagga service

Tags: bgp, quagga

I am trying to use quagga to run BGP. I installed the latest version of quagga from [source](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/quagga/). According to the documentation, I should have a /etc/quagga folder where I need to copy my bgp config as bgpd.conf

However, after installing quagga (using configure, make and make install), I did not find any folder called /etc/quagga . Also when I tried "systemcl start quagga" command, I got the following error message

```
Failed to start quagga.service: Unit quagga.service not found.
```

Have there been any changes in the source that may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Quagga does not create `/etc/quagga`, you need to do that and then create the required `bgpd.conf` (which you can do using bgpd).  As you have discovered, the `make install` does not install a `quagga.service`.